# How to make sql query?

Tags: mysql

Here is the structure of table **Likes**:

```
id(int 11)
idn(varchar 10)
type (enum ('up','down'))
```

Here is the structure of table **News**:

```
id(int 11)
idn(varchar 10)
header (varchar 100)
date(datetime)
```

To show news, I use sql query:

```
SELECT header FROM News n left join Likes l on l.idn=n.idn ORDER by n.date
```

But now I want to select headers news From table News with order by desc count rows in table Likes with type = up.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you reformulate your whole post please?

Comment: `left join Likes l ON` instead of `as`.

Comment: @Thibault sometimes we need to help users with expressing their question in correct English. OP has made an effort in putting some question but may not be as fluent as others in this language. Please try to edit the question when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query to get top liked headers for each day. If you need TOP for all dates remove `n.date` from the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT header FROM News as n 
LEFT JOIN
(
  Select idn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes  WHERE type='up' GROUP BY idn
) as l 
   ON l.idn=n.idn 
ORDER BY n.date,l.UpLikes DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.header, COUNT(i.`id`) as like_count 
FROM Likes l LEFT JOIN News n ON n.idn = l.idn 
WHERE  l.`type` = 'up' 
ORDER BY like_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this:

```
    SELECT id, idn, header, LikeCount
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT id, idn, header, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Likes]) AS [LikeCount] 
       FROM [News]    
    )
   ORDER By [LikeCount]
```

Comment: That looks like Access -- not MySQL